# Проблема с командой setlocale

Tags: bash, консоль, macos, shell

При вызове в Терминале команды **cal** календарь отображается, но выводится сообщение

```
cal: setlocale: No such file or directory
```

Когда же вызываю команду **setlocale**, получаю сообщение

```
setlocale: command not found
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне установить эту команду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/

```sh
sudo update-locale LANG=LANG=en_IN.UTF-8 LANGUAGE
```

Или

```sh
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```